# How do you drop a pin on a MapView in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-mapview

I can locate the pin for corresponding locations in `MapView`. I want to animate that pin dropping down onto the map.

How to use animation for that? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to do? From your post I'm guessing you want to animate a pin dropping down onto the map, is this correct?

Comment: yes. absoultely correct.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, take a look at this tutorial that explains how to create pin overlays:
http://www.androidguys.com/2008/09/09/maps-itemizedoverlay-and-you/

then note the onDraw method of the inherited overlay.
that's where you can animate the bonds in which the pin is drawn.

Comment: use the translation animation to interpolate the coordinates

Comment: can u give some example. i dont know about it

Answer (score 0):

Check out

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

It will show you how to use tween animations and transormations.

Comment: tween animation supports to View's Object.But not for Drawable Object.